# How to check if Visual Studio Code installed using Inno Setup?

Tags: visual-studio-code, inno-setup

Is there a way to check if Visual Studio Code is installed using Inno Setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily VS Code uses Inno Setup for install & uninstall so you can check the registry keys the Inno Setup installer creates for every setup:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{F8A2A208-72B3-4D61-95FC-8A65D340689B}_is1`

Get String value from `Inno Setup: App Path` and if not `NULL` then installed.

[image: VS Code registry]